# How to call first exported function from second exported?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to make file with four or five exports function.

```
exports.a = function() {
    // some code
    };


exports.b = function() {
       // need to call  function a
};
```

and I need from second (in this case function b to call function a) to call first exported function, but it ignores call and never enter in first function ( in this case function a).
How to call first exported function from second exported ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
var a = exports.a = function() {
    // some code
};


exports.b = function() {
   a();
};
```

Or you could use `exports.a()` in the second function, but this would mean looking up the field `a` in `exports` each time. Using `var a = ...` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern I often see is something like:

```
var a = function() {
  // ...
};

var b = function() {
  var c = a();
  // ...
  return c; // or whatever
};

// Now decide what declared variables are being exported.
module.exports = {
  a: a,
  b: b
};
```

Declare everything you want to use, then export what should be public as the last thing.